# can't initialize MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

when I try to initialize a MongoDB project , it says " 2018-07-28T21:54:34.391+0530 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: BadValue: dbPath requires an absolute file path with Windows services".

If someone knows what is the reason for that, please let me know...

my command is :

```
C:\"Program Files"\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\"Program Files"\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data\db --logpath C:\"Program Files"\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongo.log --logappend --install
```

when I try to initialize it returns an error like below...

```
2018-07-28T21:54:34.391+0530 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: BadValue: dbPath requires an absolute file path with Windows services
```

my dbpath -> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data\db

my logpath -> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongo.log

Comment: I discovered a solution for that error. I entered `mongod --remove` command and try to initialize using command below.. `mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log --logappend --install` .It works...

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the mongodb? If you haven't done the install, download the mongodb from the link and install it:

https://www.mongodb.com/dr/fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.0-signed.msi/download

1. Create the database folder from command prompt

   ```
   mkdir c:\mongodb\data\db
   ```
2. Create a folder for the log files.

   ```
   mkdir c:\mongodb\logs
   ```
3. Create a folder for the config files

   ```
   mkdir c:\mongodb\config
   ```
4. Create a file called mongodb.cfg with the following contents under the config folder c:\mongodb\config.

   ```
   port=27017
   dbpath=C:\mongodb\data\db\
   logpath=C:\mongodb\logs\mongod.log
   maxConns=100
   ```
5. Start the mongod (for a manual startup. To automate the startup, use step 6 instead)

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod" --directoryperdb --config "C:\mongodb\config\mongodb.cfg" --fork
   ```
6. Alternatively define the service

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod" --directoryperdb --config "C:\mongodb\config\mongodb.cfg" --install --serviceName "MongoDB"
    net start MongoDB
   ```

Now your database in localhost with the port 27017 is running. You can create or use the database in node.js or in your favorite programming language.

Comment: I followed your steps. But still, there is an error. when I try to run `net start MongoDB` command, it returns that `The service is not responding to the control function.` and `More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.`

Comment: Before you do "net start MongoDB", did you do this in order to install the service? `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod" --directoryperdb --config "C:\mongodb\config\mongodb.cfg" --install --serviceName "MongoDB"
`

Comment: hi @MichaelR ,  I appreciate your advice.I discovered a solution for that error. I entered `mongod --remove` command and try to initialize using command below.. `mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log --logappend --install` .After that error was gone...now it works !